# Rename page A URL with a subdomain (Redirect to new url but keep content from old url)

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, redirect

I have a landing page for mobile: abc.com/landing-page-mobile
I want to rename the URL above with my subdomain: m.abc.com
How can I do that with htaccesss file?

My idea is that redirect abc.com/landing-page-mobile to m.abc.com but KEEP the landing page content.

I have searched a lot of results but they are like redirection from abc.com/landing-page-mobile to m.abc.com and the content is from m.abc.com